# Date math with Django SQL Explorer

Tags: sql, django, sqlite, date, date-arithmetic

I have implemented Django SQL Explorer on a project and am attempting to build a query that will pull entries between today's date and 12 months prior to today's date, but I'm having a difficult time figuring out how SQL Explorer does date math.  So far, about the only thing I've been able to discover is that SQL Explorer uses current_date for today's date.

So:

```
SELECT current_date;
```

returns:

```
2021-10-02
```

I've tried using the MySQL implementation (since that's the database my project is using):

```
SELECT current_date - INTERVAL 12 MONTH;
```

returns:

```
near "12": syntax error
```

About the closest I've been able to come is some very simple math that just work on the year and strips all the rest of the date information away:

```
SELECT current_date - 1;
```

returns:

```
2020
```

Can anyone please help me figure out how to return the date 12 months prior to today's date in Django SQL Explorer?

```
SELECT current_date
SELECT current_date - [12 MONTH];
```

should return:

```
2021-10-02
2020-10-02
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you are using MySql?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you are using SQLite and not MySql, in which case you want:

```
SELECT date(CURRENT_DATE, '-12 month')
```

Or:

```
SELECT date(CURRENT_DATE, '-1 year')
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `DATE_SUB` function in MySQL syntax. for example:

`SELECT DATE_SUB('2021-10-02', INTERVAL 1 YEAR);`

or

`SELECT DATE_SUB('2021-10-02', INTERVAL 12 MONTH);`